# How to use RTSP live stream's link from tuya API?

Tags: rtsp, tuya

I've got a link from Tuya API explorer using the service "IoT Video Live Stream". I want to know where I can use this link for stream my camera's video. I have the video on my tuya APP, but I want use this link.
Here's an example of the API return.

```
{"result": {
"url": "rtsps://eb3ba0.....aa418b.....:4UBYKMX9T.....T0@aws-tractor1.tuyaus.com:443/v1/proxy/echo_show/b6721582601.....b46ac1b71.....bbb3d*****bf7.....},"success": true,"t": 1642462403630}
```

Comment: would love to get this. can get the RTSP url but can't get a stream from it.